# Randomize location of multiple objects

Tags: objects

Does anyone know if there's a modifier or any other way to "randomize" the location of a number of objects? What I have is about 20 objects positioned next to each other and I want to randomize their Z value, but it's for a still, not for animation. I'd like to know if I can do this other than manually because I may have a lot more objects than just 20...

Thanks!!

EDIT: I've found a way. **With all objects selected**, I just need to run this script:

```
import bpy
from random import *

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
  ob.location.z = ob.location.z + random() * 2
```

I wonder, however, is there's a more "visual" solution to this, other than scripting...

Comment: You can use [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html) with a random falloff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the *[Randomize Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/randomize.html?#randomize)* operator with all objects selected in *Object mode*.

Press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd> with default 2.8 keymap)and then begin typing *Randomize* until the option appears, and adjust the desired axis for location/ rotation/ scale  in the operator panel, or by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>.

You can also access the operator from the menus via *Object>Transform>Randomize transform* to do the same thing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO much!! I was disappointed Blender would not have this feature but I'm very happy it does. Yay! Hehehe... Thanks for your answer, superb.

Comment: For anyone using 2.8, space is now F3, so search with F3, and the randomize transform appears now in the object > transform.. menu.

Comment: How can we do this programmatically, such that the objects always remain in the cameras view frustum?